# Is it advisable to directly send the http request through url while requesting info from server from security point of view?

Tags: php, android-studio, kotlin, encryption, httprequest

I am using kotlin in android studio. I use this code:

```
val urlString = "http://something.com/register.php?name=$username&password=$password"

MyAsyncTask().execute(urlString)
```

*Username and password are encoded using UrlEncoder.encode(username, "utf-8")*

AsynTask has this code in doInBackground:

```
val url= URL(p0[0])
 val urlOpenConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection    
    urlConnect.connectTimeout=7000

ConverStreamToString(urlOpenConnection.inputStream)
```

And the function[ConverStreamToString] converts the urlConnect.inputStream to string so as to convert the response received to to json objects.

I'm fairly new to back end, and programming in general. My question is why people are teaching post methods, get methods etc while I can just simply send the url and get the response.. I know I should not send username and passwords through url itself, but are these request visible to user (by any means)?

If yes, How to hide/encrypt those information from the url?

This is my Register.php file:

```
<?php

require("DBInfo.inc");

//Call service to new register
//http://host/Register.php?username=something&password=1234

$query ="insert into login (username,password) values ('" . $_GET['username'] . "','" . $_GET['paasword'] . "')" ;
$result= mysqli_query($connect,$query);

if (!$result){
    $output ="{ 'msg':'fail'}" ;
}else{
    $output ="{ 'msg':'user is added'}" ;
}

print($output);

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

-> *This is my first question. So please ignore if some policies are not followed.*

Comment: All URLs are visible by anyone looking at the web traffic like a network admin or a service provider. Therefore they will be able to read your data. Any data that should be kept private must be passed trhough the body of a POST, PUT or DELETE request and via HTTPS connection because then that information will be encrypted.  For Example, when you search on Google, someone may see that you visited google, but cannot see what was the thing that you searched because that search was sent though the body of an https post request.

Comment: If anyone is willing to share their knowledge. Please tell how exactly I can use HTTPS POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, etc requests with example. I looked upon internet but there is no proper example/code for it (in kotlin). Official Documentation is so vast that it confuses me and it does not have examples(if they have, they are are really hard to understand). In short I don't know how to understand documentations like these in detail :(

Comment: @Buffalo: Not true, unless I misunderstand you. All data sent over HTTP is visible by anyone, doesn't matter if it's GET or POST or anything else. On the other hand, when using HTTPS no data is visible, whether it is GET or POST. The problem with GET is that the URL is typically logged on the server side, and bookmarked on the client side, resulting in the sensitive data being kept around forever waiting to be discovered.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk to copy someone else's answer:

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/758002.html
 "The data contained in the URL query on an HTTPS connection is
encrypted. However it is very poor practice to include such sensitive
data as a password in the a 'GET' request. While it cannot be
intercepted, the data would be logged in plaintext serverlogs on the
receiving HTTPS server, and quite possibly also in browser history"